# Parseing strictly date with SimeplDateFormat

Tags: java, apache-commons-dateutils

I'm trying to parse a date but I only get an ParseException. I'm working with the Apache DateUtils.

The code with the date that I'm tryting to parse is:

```
        Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
        System.out.println(Locale.getDefault());
        String[] list = {"EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"};
        try {
            DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("Mon, 20 Sep 2013 07:38:22 +0000",
                    list);          
        } catch (ParseException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);          
        }
```

One of the things that I did, it was to change my Locale, since my default Locale is es_ES, but it doesn't work anyway.

Why doesn't it work?

Comment: Can you try the format `EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z`

Comment: I just tried, it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using a strict parser; and September 20, 2013 was a **Friday** not a Monday.
From the [api](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/time/DateUtils.html), the parser parses strictly - it does not allow for dates such as "February 942, 1996".

```
Date d = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly(
      "Fri, 20 Sep 2013 07:38:22 +0000",
      "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
System.out.println(d);
```

Comment: Ohhh!!, thank you!!, I got that date from a streaming of twitter, I don't know why it was wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try,

```
String[] parsePattern = {"EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z"};
try {
    Date parsedDate = DateUtils.parseDateStrictly("Fri, 20 Sep 2013 07:38:22 +0000", parsePattern);
    System.out.println(" >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> parsedDate : " + parsedDate);
} catch (ParseException ex) {
    System.out.println(ex);          
}
```